# How to get the crash information from the unknow issue on real device?

Tags: ios, debugging, crash

Recently, I meet with a unknow crash without print logs, in my real device app will crash, but the simulator will not crash.

[image]

I think this is because of the cpu usage or memory rise violently.

The console did not print any crash information.

So, how to get the reason why app crash? This crash is not like other crash which can be catch and system print the issue relate infomation.

So, if it is because of the cpu usage or memory usage, how to get the relate information caused the crash?

Comment: Seems like faulty cable to me, if you have another one then try to see if it still got the error or not

Answer (score 0):

If you think that you are getting out of memory crashes, it is better to use instruments to debug and get related issues. You can use it in the following way.

Connect your device to Xcode and choose `Product -> Profile`. After profiling, select Leaks option as shown below.

[image]

You can press red button to start the app and perform all the actions leading to memory increase. If there are no memory leaks, you will get green marks as shown below. If there are memory leaks, you will see `red cross marks` (similar to ❌) and stack trace of the leak.

[image]

You can press stack trace button(Ⓔ) on left to view stack trace of the leak as shown in the below picture.

[image]

Also, you can sort the allocations list according to size and click on Ⓔ button to identify the object taking huge amount of memory.

[image]

I hope that this helps with identifying your problem. Please let me know if this doesn't help or if you need any other help in solving your problem. Please suggest edits to improve this answer :)

Comment: I know how to use intrusments, thank you any way, my question is because of suddenly high increase memory(because tableView reloadData) . In simulator will crash , but in real device it crash. and without logs.

Comment: From instruments, you got the source the memory issue as a particular method. Did you try playing around with each line of your function to track the issue?